# What is vxTas doing?

Tags: vxworks

My job is to reimplement the vxWorks function `BOOL vxTas (void * address)` for Linux

I found some documentation via google. Is it right, that vxTas checks a variable and if it is not set it will set it and returns TRUE otherwise FALSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's vxWork's implementation of a Test-and-Set instruction.

See ["Test-and-set on Wikipedia"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set)